# JSON Parsing Android from Object

Tags: java, android, json

I have a

```
         Object obj = {"RegionName":"North-1","BizPartCode":"test","BizPartName":"FRANCHISE DISTRIBUTION"}
```

Now i want to parse that to get RegionName and BizPartCode.
how to parse that ?

Comment: This has been asked and answered before **multiple times** !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(obj.toString());
String RegionName = object.getStirng("RegionName");
String BizPartCode = object.getString("BizPartCode");
```

Comment: Thanks, Feeling Stupid after seeing the answer.

Answer (score 0):

did you try ???

```
(String)obj.get("RegionName");
```